# Looking for a Isekai / transported to Otome manga the protagonist has ability to bring ingredients from original world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The protagonist was transported to an Otome game. He lives in a lonely house and goes to an academy of knights in the medieval world. He has the cheat to bring food ingredients, furniture, etc from a status screen with the help of money (given by some God). He works at a bakery for living and introduces a new kind bread there for the people. The Princess (I think was tsundere) in the academy loves to eat the MC's food.

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Gakuen Mono no Otome Game no Sekai ni Tensei shita kedo, Cheat-mochi no Haikei Danshi Seito Datta you desu.](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147138)*

> Kenta who spend time by working part time in home center, suddenly **reincarnated into a world that look like school setting otome game world that his sister liked**, moreover as a background male student character. When he reincarnated, he’s given **a magical item that can order anything that’s sold at home center where he worked at**. Reincarnated as commoner Kent, he tries his best at improving his living environment by making bakery where he work part time at the opposite side of his house prosper, but somehow the number of attractive women around him increases.

The protagonist is hit by a truck while his sister is shopping for a new otome game, and finds himself in the world of that game as a background character. He has the ability to purchase items using a tablet; one of the first things he does is purchase yeast to improve the bread at the bakery he works at.

[image: Purchased yeast]

He brings the bread with him to the academy that's the primary setting of the original game, and the princess-like villainess character sees him, tries some of the bread, and falls in love with him and his food.

[image: Villainess tries bread]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `bakery` and `reincarnation`

Answer (score 1):

My general go-to answer for having an isekai cheat ability to summon food using money is [*Campfire Cooking In Another World With My Absurd Skill*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/LightNovel/CampfireCookingInAnotherWorldWithMyAbsurdSkill) (*Tondemo Skill de Isekai Hourou Meshi*).

> Mukouda Tsuyoshi was nothing special in modern Japan, so when he was summoned to a world of swordplay and sorcery, he thought he was ready for the adventure of a lifetime. Too bad the kingdom that summoned him only got him by mistake! Not only was he not one of the three summoned heroes, but his stats were laughable compared to theirs. On top of that, there's something really sketchy about this kingdom... "Ah, these people are the kind to try and use the Hero," he realized, and immediately left to make his own way in this other world.
>
> The only thing Mukouda can rely on is his unique skill: the "Online Supermarket," a skill that allows him to buy modern goods in a fantasy world. It's useless for combat, but if he plays his cards right, he could lead a comfortable life, maybe? At least, that's what Mukouda thinks, but it turns out modern food bought with this skill has some absurd effects! What happens when Mukouda introduces ridiculously tasty modern cooking to a fantasy world like this? He gets some ridiculous repeat customers begging for more...!

That said, I don't remember anything about a knight academy. Instead, Mukouda tends to travel with adventurers. He also acquires a large number of companions who want him for his food, including a Fenrir, a slime, and at least two goddesses.